# Split byte array with string?

Tags: java

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
String sentence = "Hi there over there";
String[]result = sentence.split("there");
//you get result[0] = Hi, result[1] = over
```

Is it possible to split using the String in a byte array format?

```
byte[]delimiter = "there".getBytes();
byte[]byteSentence = sentence.getBytes();
//then somehow split byteSentence using delimiter.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, of course, convert the byte arrays into strings:

```
byte[] delimiter = "test".getBytes();
byte[] sentence = "this is a test sentence".getBytes();

String[] result = new String(sentence).split(new String(delimiter));
byte[][] resultByte = new byte[result.length][];
for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    resultByte[i] = result[i].getBytes();
}
```